# Why does my custom form finisher not exist in TYPO3 11.5.28 Composer?

Tags: typo3

My module (updated from TYPO3 10 to 11) includes a form finisher for the form framework that sends data to an API. It works like a charm in TYPO3 10. After integrating it to TYPO3 11 (composer) the following error occurs:

```
(1/2) #1278450972 TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Reflection\Exception\UnknownClassException
Class VENDOR\MODULE\Domain\Finishers\SaveApi does not exist. Reflection failed.
```

The finisher is integrated as described [here](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/11.5/en-us/I/Concepts/Finishers/Index.html#write-a-custom-finisher):

The file

```
../local_packages/MODULE/Configuration/Form/BaseSetup.yaml
```

implements the class with:

```
TYPO3:
  CMS:
    Form:
      prototypes:
        standard:
          ...
          finishersDefinition:
            SaveApi:
              implementationClassName: 'VENDOR\MODULE\Domain\Finishers\SaveApi'
          ...
```

The form definition contains the following:

```
...
finishers:
  -
    identifier: SaveApi
...
```

The finisher class itself is saved in:

```
/local_packages/MODULE/Classes/Domain/Model/Finishers/SaveApi.php
```

It contains the following:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace VENDOR\MODULE\Domain\Finishers;

class PetitionSaveApi extends \TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Finishers\AbstractFinisher
{

    /**
     * Executes this finisher
     * @throws FinisherException
     * @see AbstractFinisher::execute()
     *
     */
    protected function executeInternal()
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Is there another place where the finisher class has to be implemented?

Comment: MODULE/Classes/Domain/Model/Finishers/SaveApi.php vs  VENDOR\MODULE\Domain\Finishers => the model is missing

Comment: Thanks you, but where should I change it? I tried in BaseSetup.yaml but I did not success. The error stays the same.

Comment: the SaveApi.php misses the "Model" in the namespace

Comment: Thanks, Georg, I managed to find the problem – it had nothing to do with namespaces. It is about the file location of the Finisher. The location has to be the following directory: /local_packages/MODULE/Classes/Domain/Finishers/SaveApi.php. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all the problem was more or less simple.
The class has to be saved in the following directory:

```
/local_packages/MODULE/Classes/Domain/Finishers/SaveApi.php
```

If it is located in the model directory (as I did it in TYPO3 10) it won't work:

```
/local_packages/MODULE/Classes/Domain/Model/Finishers/SaveApi.php
```

Comment: which is basically the same what I said. Either adopt the path or the namespace - it just needs to match ;)